# Find even numbers between interval but exclude multiples of random number in Java

Tags: java, logic

I've started to learn Java very recently, and got a couple of exercises to practice. Been struggling with this one: I have to obtain 2 random numbers, A and B, and have to print all even numbers between 1 and B. I managed to do this part, but then comes the rest of the question: If a divisor of 2*A is found, the program must break and show the following message: "Multiple of 2A found". All I could do was print every even number between 1 and B, and exclude every multiple of 2*A, like this:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class JavaExercise {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random random = new Random();
        int A = random.nextInt(9) + 1;
        int B = random.nextInt(99) + 1;
        
        for (int i = 1; i <= B; ++i) {
             if ((i % 2 == 0) && (i % (2*A) != 0)) 
                 System.out.println (i);
             else
                 break;
                
        }

    }

}
```

But I need the program to break when it finds a multiple of 2*A, and shows the message above. Tried doing like this, but got a really terrible output, showing the message many times instead of once,:

```
        for (int i = 1; i <= B; ++i) {
            if (i % 2 == 0)
                 System.out.println (i);
                if (i % (2*A) == 0)
                    break;
                    System.out.println("Multiple of 2A found");
                
        }
```

Would anyone help me finding out where am I going wrong? I'd appreciate!

Comment: Why are you limiting the range of `a` compared to `b`?  Why not make them both `random.nextInt(99) + 1`

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood your question, but it was requested on the exercise: A's range must be from 1 to 10, and B's range is from 1 to 100 (sorry for any mistakes, my english is a lot rusty)

Comment: You understood it fine. The ranges were not included as a requirement in your question.  So I was just wondering why you chose them like you did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you could add a couple of print statements to see if your logic works:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class JavaExercise {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random random = new Random();
        int A = random.nextInt(9) + 1;
        int B = random.nextInt(99) + 1;
        int A_times_2 = A * 2;
        System.out.printf("A: %d, B: %d, 2A: %d%n", A, B, A_times_2);

        for (int i = 2; i <= B; i += 2) {
            if (i % A_times_2 == 0) {
                System.out.printf("Multiple of 2A found: %d%n", i);
                break;
            }
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
}
```

**Example Output:**

```
A: 9, B: 20, 2A: 18
2
4
6
8
10
12
14
16
Multiple of 2A found: 18
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I think I was thinking in a Python way (learned Python recently and decided starting Java), so I got the order os statements wrong! Also, I appreciate the idea of more print statements, they do make it a lot clearer! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

You have the lines in the wrong order.

```
        for (int i = 2; i <= B; i+=2) {
             if( i % (2*A) == 0 )
             {
                 System.out.println( "Multiple of 2A found." );
                 break;
             }
             System.out.println (i);                
        }
```